# Merge mediaplayers to 1

Tags: android

In my application i have 16 mediaplayers and i've got Equalizer for 1 mediaplayer but  i want to use it for all 16 mediaplayers at once. 
This is my Equalizer code

```
private void setupEqualizerFxAndUI() {

        mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
        mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);

        short bands = mEqualizer.getNumberOfBands();

        final short minEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
        final short maxEQLevel = mEqualizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];

        for (short i = 0; i < bands; i++) {
            final short band = i;
```

as you see it is using mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId, that is only one of 16 mediaplayers, those are my mediaplayers. Should i set up more equalizers or there is way to merge mediaplayers to one?

```
 MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer1;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer2;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer3;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer4;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer5;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer6;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer7;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer8;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer9;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer10;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer11;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer12;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer13;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer14;
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer15;
```

Comment: Why on earth do you need so many MediaPlayers?

Comment: Every MediaPlayer plays different sounds, I tried soundpools but sounds plays only 6 seconds.

Comment: Don't do this, MediaPlayer is a very heavyweight object. Suggest you look into AudioTrack: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

Comment: AudioTrack doesnt have all the options i need.